# T-SQL: How to select rows based on the max date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which has two fields which I want to make a decision on:

```
- DATE
- DATE_LOADED
```

I want to know if there is a DATE (which may have many associated lines), say '`2016-06-15`', which has two unique DATE_LOADED entries, `'2016-06-16'` and `'2016-06-17'`, then take the MAX DATE_LOADED lines only.

In real terms, two reports have been reporting overlapping data for the same day. The later report is a correction. All columns may have updated but DATE.

**ASK:**
 For each DATE (not just each individual line), check if there is more than one DATE_LOADED, if there is then take **all lines associated with that DATE** and where DATE_LOADED = MAX DATE_LOADED for that particular date.

Comment: please provide data sample and required output result, and also it will be greate if you will provide your own atempts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using window functions

```
select *
from (
   select t.*, 
          row_number() over (partition by date order by date_loaded desc) as rn
   from the_table t
) x
where rn = 1;
```

If there are multiple rows with the same max date, the above would only return one of them. If you want all, you can use something like this:

```
select *
from (
   select t.*, 
          max(date_loaded) over (partition by date) as max_date_loaded
   from the_table t
) x
where date_loaded = max_date_loaded;
```

If you want to filter out DATEs with just a single DATE_LOADED, you can enhance the query to:

```
select *
from (
   select t.*, 
          max(date_loaded) over (partition by date) as max_date_loaded,
          count(*) over (partition by date) as cnt
   from the_table t
) x
where date_loaded = max_date_loaded
  and cnt > 1;
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! I took the second example because there are multiple rows with the same max date. That was the point of the question. In your code you are missing some words after 'order' on the 4th line, either order it by something, or delete the order keyword, but it won't work the way it is. Thanks!

Comment: @ColinO'Brien: thanks, corrected. `max()` doesn't need an `order by` at all.

Answer (score 3):

This query will get you a list of `DATE`, the total number of different `DATE_LOADED` values for that date, and the maximum `DATE_LOADED` value across those records.

```
SELECT DATE
   , COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_LOADED) AS [Total Different DATE_LOADED Values]
   , MAX(DATE_LOADED) AS [Max DATE_LOADED]
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY DATE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_LOADED) > 1
```

---

I saw this later on

> then take all lines associated with that DATE and where DATE_LOADED = MAX DATE_LOADED for that particular date.

This can be accomplished by joining the query above back to your table. This will yield a result of all records in your original table matching on the previous query.

```
SELECT yt.* 
FROM YOURTABLE AS yt INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DATE
       , MAX(DATE_LOADED) AS [Max DATE_LOADED]
    FROM YOURTABLE
    GROUP BY DATE
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_LOADED) > 1
    ) AS subQry ON yt.DATE = subQry.DATE AND yt.DATE_LOADED = subQry.[Max DATE_LOADED]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CROSS APPLY or INNER JOIN for this purpose. Below is an example with CROSS APPLY.

```
SELECT  t.[DATE],
        t.DATE_LOADED    
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(DATE_LOADED) as MAX_DATE_LOADED 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE [DATE] = t.[DATE]) as p
WHERE t.DATE_LOADED = p.MAX_DATE_LOADED
```

For example if in your table there is something like:

```
DATE        DATE_LOADED
2016-06-15  2016-06-16
2016-06-15  2016-06-17
2016-06-15  2016-06-18
2016-06-15  2016-06-18
```

Above query will give you:

```
DATE        DATE_LOADED
2016-06-15  2016-06-18
2016-06-15  2016-06-18
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are after something like below

```
Select Date,MAX(DateLoaded)
From TableName    
Group By Date
```